# Remove anything between two character

Tags: java

i want to remove anything between "?" and "/"

my text is `"hi?0/hello/hi"`

i need to see this out put

```
"hi?/hello/hi"
```

My Code Is

```
key.replaceAll("\\?.*/","?/");
```

but my Output Is

```
"hi?/hi"
```

whats wrong?

Comment: i can't do that with split or something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using greedy matching, so it matches up to the next slash too. Try:

```
key.replaceAll("\\?.*?/","?/");
```

An alternative still using greedy matching is to match any character except `/`:

```
key.replaceAll("\\?[^/]*/","?/");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
key.replaceAll("\\?.*?/","?/")
```

You can read more about `greedy`and `non greedy` matching [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)